# Creating a Cursor and Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor, record

I created a Cursor for a procedure.  I am trying to apply a flag to records in that cursor.

```
Create or Replace Procedure Pledges 
(IDdonor In Int)
is 
Cursor Cur_Pledges is 
Select dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_status.idstatus from dd_donor
join dd_pledge on dd_donor.iddonor=dd_pledge.iddonor
join dd_status on dd_pledge.idstatus=dd_status.idstatus;
Type All_Pledges2 is record(iddonor dd_pledge.iddonor%type, idstatus dd_status.idstatus%type, flag Varchar2(10));
Begin
  For Rec_Pledges in Cur_Pledges LOOP
    if rec_pledges.idstatus = '10' THEN Flag := 'True';
      elsif rec_pledges.idstatus= '20' THEN Flag := 'False';
    End if;
  Insert Into All_Pledges
    Values(rec_pledges.idddonor, rec_pledges.idstatus, flag);
  End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Please expand the post with what is not working, the result you get (and what you expect), error messages. That might lower the threshold for potential answerers finding an answer. Don't put stuff like **Edit** or **Update** in your question when you do revise. This site has edit history, those who need to see differences can get the information from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrongly using the type record variable, I have made the changes please check below, this will work:

```
Create or Replace Procedure Pledges 
(IDdonor In Int)
is 
Cursor Cur_Pledges is 
Select dd_pledge.iddonor, dd_status.idstatus from dd_donor
join dd_pledge on dd_donor.iddonor=dd_pledge.iddonor
join dd_status on dd_pledge.idstatus=dd_status.idstatus;
Type All_Pledges2 is record(iddonor dd_pledge.iddonor%type, idstatus dd_status.idstatus%type, flag Varchar2(10));
-- new change below
allpledges2 All_Pledges2;
Begin
  For Rec_Pledges in Cur_Pledges LOOP
    if rec_pledges.idstatus = '10' THEN 
      allpledges2.Flag := 'True';
      elsif rec_pledges.idstatus= '20' THEN 
      allpledges2.Flag := 'False';
    End if;
  Insert Into All_Pledges
    Values(rec_pledges.iddonor, rec_pledges.idstatus, allpledges2.flag);
  End Loop;
End;
```

Comment: Changes were made as suggested but still receive an error at-
'Values(rec_pledges.iddonor, rec_pledges.idstatus, allpledges2.flag); '
Errors that I am receiving are SQL statement ignored and PL/SQL table or view does not exist

Comment: Is there table all_pledges ? If not then you must create first.

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with a cursor loop, you shouldn't. Generally, PL/SQL performs best if you minimize the number of context changes and let the SQL optimizer do it's job. This procedure should consist of a single `insert` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pledges (iddonor IN INT) IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO all_pledges
      SELECT dd_pledge.iddonor,
             dd_status.idstatus,
             CASE dd_status.idstatus
                WHEN '10' THEN 'True'
                WHEN '20' THEN 'False'
             END
      FROM   dd_donor
             JOIN dd_pledge ON dd_donor.iddonor = dd_pledge.iddonor
             JOIN dd_status ON dd_pledge.idstatus = dd_status.idstatus;
END pledges;
```

It probably worth noting that, as written, the `iddonor` parameter is superfluous: since you aren't referencing it in the code, it serves no purpose.

---

If the goal is to simply return the results to another program, you don't want an insert at all (using a table to return a result set is not a good pattern in Oracle). The best way to handle that is typically to open a ref cursor and return that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pledges (iddonor IN INT,
                                     all_pledges OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) IS
BEGIN
   OPEN all_pledges FOR
      SELECT dd_pledge.iddonor,
             dd_status.idstatus,
             CASE dd_status.idstatus
                WHEN '10' THEN 'True'
                WHEN '20' THEN 'False'
             END
      FROM   dd_donor
             JOIN dd_pledge ON dd_donor.iddonor = dd_pledge.iddonor
             JOIN dd_status ON dd_pledge.idstatus = dd_status.idstatus
      WHERE  dd_donor.iddonor = pledges.iddonor;
END pledges;
```

Alternately, you could return a user-defined type or write the results to a global temporary table.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need to create a program that will use the donorid as the parameter that will be passed to this program.  I actually dont want to create a permenant table something that I can use to display the results once the cursor has completed